# Change index of multiple dataframes at once

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
Here is my earlier part of the code - 
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

a= pd.read_excel(r'D:\Ph.D. IEE\IEE 6570 - IR Dr. Greene\3machinediverging.xlsx')
question = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index('Job')
df2 = question.index
permutations = list(it.permutations(question.index))

dfper = pd.DataFrame(permutations)
for i in range(len(dfper)):
    fr = dfper.iloc[0:len(dfper)]
fr.index.name = ''
print(fr)

for i in range(0, fr.shape[0], 1):
    print (fr.iloc[i:i+1].T)
```

This gives me 120 dataframes.

```py
    0
0   A

1   B

2   C

3   D

4   E


    1
0   A

1   B

2   C

3   E

4   D
```

and so on...

I would like to change the index of these dataframes to the alphabet column (using a for loop). Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have 120 separate dataframes?

Comment: Because I would like to add 4 numerical columns to each of the dataframe and perform some analysis so as to compare all 120 dataframes to find the best output

Comment: How are you storing your dataframes?

Comment: I have edited the question for your reference. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1:  [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})

df_list =  [df1, df2]

for df in df_list:
    # set the first column as index
    df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would organize all dataframes in a list:

```py
df_list = [df1, df2, df3,...]
```

and then:

```py
for df in df_list: df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be like manually entering all 120 dataframes? and 120 column names?

Comment: Where do these dataframes come from? How did you create them? If the problem is to organise all of them in a list I guess it means that you wrote each of them one by one?

Comment: Regarding the column name you were right, I did not read carefully your question. I edited the answer so that it always sets as index the first column of the dataframe regardless of the column name